# After byte shifitng a int to 4 bytes, how can I shift back to int (C)

Tags: c

So I byte shift a integer into 4 bytes of data.

```
img[4] = (imagewidth >> 24) & 0xFF;
img[5] = (imagewidth >> 16) & 0xFF;
img[6] = (imagewidth >> 8) & 0xFF;
img[7] = imagewidth & 0xFF;

img[8] = (imageheight >> 24) & 0xFF;
img[9] = (imageheight >> 16) & 0xFF;
img[10] = (imageheight >> 8) & 0xFF;
img[11] = imageheight & 0xFF;
```

Now how would I go about shifting it back to an integer. so `img[8]` - `img[11]` back to a single `int` or `img[4]` - `img[7]` back to a single `int`

Comment: I that correct if I induce that your `imagewidth` and `imageheight` variables are just `int`. You should have them `unsigned` or even better `uint32_t` since you are assuming 32 bit.

Comment: Make sure that `img[]` is declared as `unsigned char`. If not, then you will run into interesting issues when doing arithmetic to reassemble the individual bytes into larger values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
imagewidth = img[4] << 24 | img[5] << 16 | img[6] << 8 | img[7];
imageheight = img[8] << 24 | img[9] << 16 | img[10] << 8 | img[11];
```

Comment: Hopefully `img[]` was declared `unsigned char` so that you don't get sign extension when the individual bytes are promoted to `int` before each shift. Writing it as `img[4] << 24U | ...` would be a way to make intent clearer to the compiler and protect against that mistake by requiring that each subexpression promote to `unsigned int` instead of `int`.

Comment: @RBerteig: I think the right operand on a shift has no influence on the result type, so this wouldn't help. And for negative values left shift is simply undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jens, You are right, the LHS of a shift controls the type of the result, not the RHS. And left shifts of signed types are fraught with undefined behaviors. That strengthens my first point. The byte array has to be declared as `unsigned char` or the arithmetic will invoke undefined behavior.